# Не загружаются картинки

Tags: html, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина? Даже если я просто изменяю готовые(дефолтные) картинки, на свои, с таким же размером (1500х1000), форматом (jpg) и названием, то всё равно они не отображаются, как я представил это на скринах ниже. В чем здесь вся фишка? Я кликаю по первой стандартной фотке, открывается увеличенная, меняю на свою, ничего не открывается, когда кликаю... не понимаю.... помогите пожалуйста, уж очень мне это портфолио понравилось, а настроить не могу (

```css
.portfolio {
background:#f1f1f1;
}  
/* gallery */
.gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.gallery .mix {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.gallery .mix.full {
    height: auto;
}
.gallery a.mix-cover img {
    width: 100%;
 
}
.gallery a.mix-cover, .gallery span.cover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery.portfolio a.mix-cover, .gallery.portfolio a.mix-cover .overlay {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.gallery .mix a img, .gallery .mix a span.overlay {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.gallery a.mix-cover {
    position: relative;
    transition: top 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.gallery span.cover {
    background-color: #F4D432;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
}
.gallery span.cover span {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
img.placeholder {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Overlay */
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
    border: 0 solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    z-index: 9;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.overlay i, .overlay span.title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.overlay span.title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.overlay:hover i, .overlay:hover span.title {
    top: 10px;
}

span.valign {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
  
  <div class="gallery">
  
        <ul id="Grid" class="gcontainer">
          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix bw portraits" data-cat="graphics">
              <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portrait1" class="mix-cover">
                <img class="horizontal" src="img/portrait1-sm.jpg" alt="placeholder">
              <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Portrait 1</span></span>
              </a>                
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix portraits" data-cat="graphics">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portrait2" class="mix-cover">
                  <img class="horizontal" src="img/portrait2.jpg" alt="placeholder">
                <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Portrait 2</span></span>
                </a>                
          </li>
     <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix nature" data-cat="nature">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nature1" class="mix-cover">
                  <img class="horizontal" src="img/nature1.jpg" alt="placeholder">
                <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Nature 1</span></span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix portraits" data-cat="portraits">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portrait3" class="mix-cover">
                  <img class="horizontal" src="img/portrait3.jpg" alt="placeholder">
                <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Portrait 3</span></span>
              </a>
          </li>
     <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix portraits" data-cat="portraits">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portrait5" class="mix-cover">
                  <img class="horizontal" src="img/portrait5.jpg" alt="placeholder">
                 <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Portrait 5</span></span>
              </a>
          </li>
     <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix nature" data-cat="nature">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nature" class="mix-cover">
                  <img class="horizontal" src="img/nature.jpg" alt="placeholder">
                <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Nature</span></span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix portraits" data-cat="portrait">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portrait4" class="mix-cover green">
                  <img class="vertical" src="img/portrait4.jpg" alt="portrait 4">
                  <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Portrait 4</span></span>           
              </a>
          </li>
     <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix bw nature all" data-cat="portrait">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forest" class="mix-cover green">
                  <img class="vertical" src="img/forest.jpg" alt="Forest">
                   <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Forest</span></span>                    
              </a>
          </li>
     <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 mix bw nature all" data-cat="bw">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bw1" class="mix-cover green">
                  <img class="vertical" src="img/bw1.jpg" alt="Black and White">
                   <span class="overlay"><span class="valign"></span><span class="title">Black &amp; White</span></span>                  
              </a>
          </li>
        </ul>   
     
<!-- Load Photo in Modal -->     
   <div class="modal fade" id="portrait1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Portrait 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="Portrait1" src="img/portrait1.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="portrait2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Portrait 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="Portrait1" src="img/portrait2.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="portrait3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Portrait 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="Portrait1" src="img/portrait3.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="portrait4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Portrait 4</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="Portrait1" src="img/portrait4.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="portrait5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Portrait 5</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="Portrait1" src="img/portrait5.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="nature" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Nature</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="nature" src="img/nature.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="nature1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Nature 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="nature" src="img/nature1.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


<div class="modal fade" id="forest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Forest</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="forest" src="img/forest.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="bw1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Black and White</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <img class="thumbnail" alt="forest" src="img/bw1.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->


<!-- /Load Photo in Modal --> 
  </div> 
      </div>
  </div>
      </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: путь у вас точно верный?
может у вас хтмл файл лежит в папке отдельной?

Comment: Там на каждую картинку 2 картинки - маленькая и большая. Обе поставлены?

Comment: Oleksandr путь точный, к сожалению(
labris там есть portrait2 и другие, которые содержат одну картинку, которая в мини виде , а когда кликаешь, просто открывается... ((

Answer (score -1):

Стыдно признать, но не думал, что `jpg` и `jpeg` разные форматы.

Ошибка была в этом: `/close`